# How would "simply" loop over three lists without repetition in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, sh

Dears, I have a code to generate many text files, and I faced a problem that the code takes time as a result of repetitions so, how "simply" I add a command in bash .sh script and exclude the repeating values e.g.  (0.45, 0.45,0.50) is used but (0.45,0.50,0.45) and (0.50,0.45,0.45) ... are excluded

```
i = 0

for VX1 in 0.45 0.50 0.55
 do

for VX2 in 0.45 0.50 0.55
 do

for VX3 in 0.45 0.50 0.55
 do
let "i++"
```

Comment: `(0.45, 0.45,0.50)` has repeating values `0.45`, why is it used?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What array is in this question>?

Comment: @Barmar Ahh -- I read VX1, VX2 and VX3 as three separate arrays we wanted to iterate over (where they just happened to be using the same sample data for each). Without that assumption... honestly, I'm having a lot more trouble making heads or tails of what the OP actually wants to accomplish.

Comment: I don't really understand the criteria, but you basically just need an `if` statement in the inner loop that checks whether the values meet your criteria for inclusion before generating the filename.

Comment: Could you please post some complete, runnable code sample instead of just some partial snippet.

Comment: How is it that `(0.45, 0.45,0.50)` is taken as *not* containing repeated values?

Comment: @MuradAlDamen : Your variables (VX1 etc.) are not arrays, but scalars. Also, your posted code is lacking the `done` statements inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the values are equal right after starting an inner loop. Use `continue` to skip an iteration.

To test against two values, you can use an `extglob` pattern in bash.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
i=0
shopt -s extglob
for VX1 in 0.45 0.50 0.55 ; do
    for VX2 in 0.45 0.50 0.55 ; do
        if [[ "$VX2" == "$VX1" ]] ; then
            continue
        fi
        for VX3 in 0.45 0.50 0.55 ; do
            if [[ "$VX3" == @("$VX2"|"$VX1") ]] ; then
                continue
            fi
            let "i++"
        done
    done
done
echo $i
```

Comment: Thank you @choroba ,  you made my day!